# CrossSim Package Issue

Tags: python

The GitHub page for CrossSim and the Crossbar Simulator Page only provide installation packages for versions 2.0 and 3.0. Does anyone have the installation package for version 0.2.0?

Or somewhere to download this package.

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)